# a custom image on each node in cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

I would like to use Cytoscape to have all glyphs of an ideographic font with lots of contextual alternates and other extras represented as a network graph. For me it is critical to have a glyph image on each node to track and control relations between them. So far, I've learned how to use styles to assign background images to nodes, but this changes all nodes at once, which doesn't help much. I would appreciate your help on whether it's possible to achieve my goal by some built-in function of Cytoscape, or programmatically, or by any other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for a Discrete Mapping Function.

Switch to the Style control panel, select the Image/Chart1 property, and open the triangle.  Select the column you want to map to your glyph, and select Discrete Mapping as the Mapping Type.

Then assign your images.  This information can be saved as an xml visual style sheet.

This points to the [styles page in the manual](http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Styles.html#advanced-topics)