# How to automatically display an image on each node in Cytoscape

Tags: python, cytoscape

I have a Cytoscape (3.7.1) network with a node attribute "source_img". This contains the path leading to the corresponding image I would like to represent on the node.

I found this post: [a custom image on each node in cytoscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887779/a-custom-image-on-each-node-in-cytoscape) for using discrete mapping with images, but the user is required to select and edit each node/image pairs, which is not ideal for me, because:

1. I have over 1000 nodes-images pairs, as it was not tedious enough Cytoscape Image Manager takes a long time for starting up.
2. I might have to do this with another images later.

So far I tried the following:

1. set a default value for the discrete mapping
2. export the cytoscape styles.xml file
3. edit the image paths of the discrete mapping directly in the xml file

I was unsuccessful as I don't know the id of the image in the Image Manager, which is apparently required as well in the xml.

> Example of an entry in the styles.xml file (node='1674', image='1674.png' and id=3 in bold):
>
> discreteMappingEntry attributeValue="/home/josemanuel/Tests/images/1674.png" value="org.cytoscape.ding.customgraphics.bitmap.URLImageCustomGraphics,**3**,/home/josemanuel/Tests/images/1674.png,bitmap image"/>

I also tried (and failed) to apply a Passthrough Mapping instead, so I guess only the file path is not enough for this to work?

I have no experience with py2cytoscape, but I could not find any example for applying a discrete map for images either.

How could I display the corresponding images on the nodes automatically?

Here is an illustration of what I would like to achieve:

[image: Simple illustration with images of letters]

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it following this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US/#!searchin/cytoscape-helpdesk/image|sort:date/cytoscape-helpdesk/nmSPX5AcY4U/V7-2BE5VAgAJ

The key was to use as node attribute not the path linking to the corresponding image file, but its URL (file:///home/josemanuel/...).

Still it did not work right away. There seems to be a limitation regarding the location of the images themselves. I don't have any special characters in URL linking to the image files (just alphanumerical and underscores), but when I copied/pasted the whole image folders to a shorter location directly in my home folder, the images were displayed as I wanted.

I hope it can be useful to someone!

Cheers,
Jose Manuel